# How to Bind Multiple Choice Quiz Answer in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a form in VueJS that allows a user to create a quiz using various question types. One of those question types is Multiple Choice. Currently, this is my data structure for the new quiz...

```
newQuiz: {
   title: '',
   questions: [

   ],
}
```

And this is the structure for Multiple Choice questions...

```
this.newQuiz.questions.push({
    id: count+'mc',
    type: 'mc',
    question: 'Example',
    correct: 0,
    answers: [
        'First answer',
        'Second answer',
        'Third answer',
        'Fourth answer'
    ]
});
```

Currently, I have a `v-for` running on a div that creates each question, giving the radio buttons their proper labels, name, etc. Each radio button and it's respective label has an `@click` that runs a function as such...

```
this.newQuiz.questions[question].correct = answer;
```

I was curious if I could bind the radio buttons to the correct value, so that no updating function is necessary, or so that the default shows selected properly?

For context, here's the `v-for` as well.

```
<div v-for="(question, qIndex) in this.newQuiz.questions" :key="question.id">
    <div v-if="question.type='mc'" class="mb-8">
        <label class="block">{{ question.question }}</label>
        <div v-for="(answer, aIndex) in question.answers" :key="answer">
            <input type="radio" :id="question.id+'-'+aIndex" :name="question.id" @click="updateMCAnswer(qIndex, aIndex)">
            <label :for="question.id+'-'+aIndex" @click="updateMCAnswer(qIndex, aIndex)">{{ answer }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So `correct` actually holds the user's last selection rather than the correct answer?  (Since `correct` is set on `@click` like that.)  What should happen if the answer is correct?  Show `updateMCAnswer` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bind the answer directly to the `correct` field of the corresponding question, try the following code

```
    <div v-for="(question, qIndex) in this.newQuiz.questions" :key="question.id">
        <div v-if="question.type='mc'" class="mb-8">
            <label class="block">{{ question.question }}</label>
            <div v-for="(answer, aIndex) in question.answers" :key="answer">
                <input type="radio" :id="question.id+'-'+aIndex" :name="question.id" v-model="question.correct"
                       :value="answer">
                <label :for="question.id+'-'+aIndex" @click="updateMCAnswer(qIndex, aIndex)">{{ answer }}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can remove the `click` event and directly bind the value by adding `v-model="question.correct"` and `:value="answer"` to the `input` field.